# get cumulative sum dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas

I tried several times in pandas

input =>

```
data = {'count': [2,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,1]}
```

output =>

```
data = {'count': [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]}
```

but results was poor.

Can i get any solutions?

I'll leave my code.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'error_count': [2,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,1]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['error_count'] = df['error_count'].replace(0, method='ffill')

last_value = df['error_count'].iloc[-1]
if last_value > 0:
    df.loc[df['error_count'] != last_value, 'error_count'] += last_value

print(df)
```

count: [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Sorry, what are you asking? If you want a cumulative sum, you can use `.cumsum()`, but that doesn't seem to be what you want. Check out [ask] for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

use `where` & `cumsum`

```
cond = df['count'].ne(df['count'].shift())
out = df['count'].where(cond, 0).cumsum()
```

out :

```
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    4
8    4
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'count': [2,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

check with new example

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'count': [3,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

cond = df1['count'].ne(df1['count'].shift())
out = df1['count'].where(cond, 0).cumsum()
```

df1 & out:

```
df1                 out

    count   
0   3               3
1   2               5
2   2               5
3   2               5
4   1               6
5   0               6
6   0               6
7   1               7
8   1               7
```

Comment: data = {'count': [2,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,0,0,1,2],
         'ID':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new_count'] = ((df['count'].ne(df['count'].shift())) & (df['count'].ne(0))).cumsum() + 1
I added ID columns

Comment: @MagicStick If you want to receive code with a new example, update the question. Also, write the desired output of the new example.

Comment: Ok thankyou. I'll write new question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way, but you can use this. It checks if the value from
the current row is not equal with the current value and if the value of the current row is not equal to 0. If is True, then it applies cumsum(), else returns the previous value of the result of cumsum().

```
df['new_count'] = ((df['count'].ne(df['count'].shift())) & (df['count'].ne(0))).cumsum() + 1
```

end result:

```
count   new_count
2       2
2       2
2       2
2       2
1       3
0       3
0       3
1       4
1       4
```